# Match two arrays and put post in pending if no IDs match

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm somewhat confused and need some assistance from the community, so I have a piece of code that I'm working on and I would like to compare two arrays and then if IDs don't match, to put the post in pending state.

**I have the following method**:

```
/**
 * Update Office titles
 */
function update_office_titles() {
    $office_data = build_offices_array();
    $compare_ids = [];
    foreach ($office_data as $office) {
        $compare_ids[] = [
            'wp_office_id' => $office['office_id']
        ];
    }
    foreach (api_offices_raw() as $api_office_id) {
        $compare_ids[] = [
            'api_id' => $api_office_id->id
        ];
    }

    print_r($compare_ids);

    echo 'All of the office titles have been updated';
}
```

Here, I'm grabbing all the `office_id` post_meta and getting all the post_meta values in the DB:

```
foreach ($office_data as $office) {
    $compare_ids[] = [
        'wp_office_id' => $office['office_id']
    ];
}
```

I get the following return:

```
[243] => Array
    (
        [wp_office_id] => 3
    )

[244] => Array
    (
        [wp_office_id] => 4
    )
```

Then I have this foreach that loops through an API with IDs:

```
foreach (api_offices_raw() as $api_office_id) {
    $compare_ids[] = [
        'api_id' => $api_office_id->id
    ];
}
```

I get this output:

```
[246] => Array
    (
        [api_id] => 1
    )

[247] => Array
    (
        [api_id] => 3
    )
```

Here is what I was attempting to achieve:

Check `api_id`'s and match them to the `wp_office_id` key values, if there are matching IDs, don't do nothing, otherwise call a wp_update_post and set the status to pending on `$office['post_id']` on all IDs from `wp_office_id` that don't match.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure where you would get those array keys from, when you are doing `$compare_ids[] = …` - should start at zero then, unless you only shown us a small part of much bigger arrays here?

Comment: Go look into `array_diff`. (You will have to “reduce” your arrays back to flat ones holding only the IDs … or you don’t create them in this convoluted way to begin with, if that structure does not serve any other actual purpose elsewhere?)